# How to read values corresponding to a key separated by backslash in c++

Tags: c++, ini

I have a section in ini file which i want to read and parse in C++

I tried to read it with the help of GetPrivateProfileString but it reads upto "$THIS$=somevalue",\ and doesn't read further.

file.ini

```
[Mysection]
UserDefinedVariables="$THIS$=somevalue",\
"$THAT$=somevalue1",\
"$DEVICE1$=somevalue2",\
"$DEVICE2$=somevalue3",\
"$DEVICE3$=somevalue4"
```

c++ file

```
wchar_t deviceName[200];
GetPrivateProfileString(L"Mysection", L"UserDefinedVariables", NULL, deviceName, sizeof(deviceName), file.ini);
```

Here I'm particulary interested in value corresponding to $DEVICE1$ i.e. somevalue2.
Is there any way i could make use of windows API's to read it?

Comment: Lines ending with '\' are meant to be combined with the following line by removing the '\' and the newline.

Comment: Your INI file is invalid as far as `GetPrivateProfileString` is concerned. Note that this function (and INI files!) also shouldn’t be used any more, it’s provided for compatibility only.

Comment: Boost fails to handle such input: https://wandbox.org/permlink/t4bi58F6vySXEkRA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use this function. But I doubt that it is what you want to do.

The problems is that your input file is wrong. The \ at the end is normally a concatenator for lines. So, all text should be in one line. Then the result should be parsed.

The next lines are seen again as keys with a value.

But the key is not $DEVICE1$ as you would expect, but "$DEVICE1$. Please see the additional ". Please read the functions [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring).

If you search for that key, you will get a result. But here again with an appended ".

So the format of the following lines is not correct and the reason is what I explained before. To see, how this functions work (which you should not use in the first place) please see the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t deviceName[400];

    GetPrivateProfileString(L"Mysection", L"UserDefinedVariables", NULL, deviceName, sizeof(deviceName), L"r:\\file.ini");
    std::wcout << "searching for key UserDefinedVariables --> " << deviceName << '\n';


    // Get all keys
    std::wcout << "\n\nSearching for all keys in section:\n";
    DWORD size = GetPrivateProfileString(L"Mysection", NULL, NULL, deviceName, sizeof(deviceName), L"r:\\file.ini");

    DWORD start = 0;
    wchar_t keys[10][100];
    DWORD keyIndex = 0;

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (deviceName[i] == 0) {
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
            wcscpy(keys[keyIndex], deviceName + start);
            start = i + 1;
            std::wcout << keys[keyIndex] << '\n';
            ++keyIndex;
        }
    }

    // Getting all values for the keys
    std::wcout << "\n\nSearching for all keys with values in section:\n";

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < keyIndex; ++i) {
        GetPrivateProfileString(L"Mysection", keys[i], NULL, deviceName, sizeof(deviceName), L"r:\\file.ini");
        std::wcout << keys[i] << " -->  " << deviceName << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
searching for key UserDefinedVariables --> "$THIS$=somevalue",\


Searching for all keys in section:
UserDefinedVariables
"$THAT$
"$DEVICE1$
"$DEVICE2$
"$DEVICE3$


Searching for all keys with values in section:
UserDefinedVariables -->  "$THIS$=somevalue",\
"$THAT$ -->  somevalue1",\
"$DEVICE1$ -->  somevalue2",\
"$DEVICE2$ -->  somevalue3",\
"$DEVICE3$ -->  somevalue4"
```

You can then extract your values like you wish.

But as I said. Better to correct the ini file.